# Cannot find module "gulp-nodemon". On windows 7, 32 bit. Using Power Shell

Tags: node.js, gulp, nodemon

I am new to Node.js. I am trying to learn it through doing something.
I am making an Sentiment Analysis App for twitter.
I am using Gulp.
However, whenever I use "gulp" in my cmd. Note that I have installed Nodemon.
I get the following error :

```
Error: Cannot find module 'gulp-nodemon'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous>   (C:\Users\home\desktop\sentimentAnalysisApp\Gulpfile.js:4:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

Also, I am following this [tutorial].
http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-sentiment-analysis-application-using-node-js/

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install `gulp-nodemon` as well.

Try `npm install -g gulp-nodemon`.